# React Native and support for Android Auto, Apple CarPlay, and wearables

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm about to begin building out an app using React Native. It's a simple audio player that plays music. However, on top of having an audio player in the app, I would also like to support:

- Android Auto
- Apple CarPlay
- Wearables

Does React Native support these platforms out of the box? How good is the integration? Will I run into many bumps along the way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

About Apple Car Play you can use [react-native-carplay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-carplay), but before use it I see expo tag in your question **if you are using expo to create you application it's not supported in a expo**. read this article to know more how implement [add Car Play to your React Native App](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/add-carplay-to-your-react-native-app)

about [wearables](https://github.com/yldio/react-native-wearables) check the repo to know more.

> How good is the integration? Will I run into many bumps along the way?
> If you are using TypeScript it's will be easy to do, and you have much repos and articles explain how to implement those packages with mobile application